# ReactJS and Google Maps API not Rendering Correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I'm a relatively new ReactJS learner, and I'm trying to show a Google Map of an address that you enter using ReactJS. I'm getting a strange appearance when I click the submit button of a valid address, and I have window.alert messages telling me I'm getting the lat and long that I expect:
[image]
And I also encounter these messages in the console, which I've read is because the way React interacts with the DOM isn't what Google's API expects.

[image]

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        .map-gic {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px
        }
        body{
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" style="height:500px; width:500px; position: absolute;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        var apiKey = "";
        var AddressForm = React.createClass({
            handleSubmit: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var address = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.address).value.trim();
                if (!address) {
                    // handle errors
                }
                this.props.onAddressSubmit(address);
            },
              render: function() {
                return (
                  <form className="address" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="enter address" ref="address"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
                  </form>
                );
              }
        });         
        var AddressBox = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function () {
                return {lat: 0, lng: 0};
            },
            displayMap: function(address) {
                var fixedAddress = address.trim().replace(" ","+");
                var request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + fixedAddress + "&key=" + apiKey;
                $.ajax({
                    url: request,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: address,
                    success: function(data) {
                        var location = data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"];
                        //window.alert("lat is " + location["lat"] + ", and lng is " + location["lng"]);
                        this.setState({lat: location["lat"], lng: location["lng"]});
                    }.bind(this),
                    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                        console.error(status, err.toString());
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            },
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <div className="addressBox">
                        <h1>Look up an address to see its location</h1>
                        <AddressForm onAddressSubmit={this.displayMap}/>
                        <GoogleMap lat={this.state.lat} lng={this.state.lng}/>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });

        var GoogleMap = React.createClass({
            componentDidUpdate: function() {
                var lat = this.props.lat;
                var lng = this.props.lng;
                window.alert("lat is " + lat + ", and lng is " + lng);
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(this.getDOMNode(), mapOptions);
            },
            render: function() {
                return(
                    <div className='map-gic'></div>
                );
            }
        });
        React.render(
          <AddressBox/>,
          document.getElementById('content')
        );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: I have taken out my API key, because I'm not sure if I should share that or not.

To summarize:

1. What's going on and how do I fix it?
2. Is there anything else specific to this ReactJS code chunk that I could improve?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the line numbers for those errors? (Line numbers are shown on the far right of the error)

Comment: They are like line 3000 in Google's or React's code, but I can get exact numbers if you need them.